# Cannot convert value of UnsafeMutableRawPointer to BluetoothDeviceAddress

Tags: swift, xcode, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to convert this source code :

```
BluetoothDeviceAddress *deviceAddress = malloc(sizeof(BluetoothDeviceAddress));
```

to Swift, which gives me :

```
let deviceAddress: BluetoothDeviceAddress = malloc(sizeof(BluetoothDeviceAddress))
```

But, I found that in Swift 3/4, `sizeof` is not used anymore but this is not my error, Xcode returns :

"Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeMutableRawPointer!' to specified type 'BluetoothDeviceAddress'"

I tried changing to `malloc(MemoryLayout<BluetoothDeviceAddress>.size)` but still the same error.

EDIT:
As proposed in the comments by MartinR, I tried changing to `let deviceAddress = BluetoothDeviceAddress()`
but then when I want to initialize an IOBluetoothDevice, I still get an error (selectedDevice is a var for IOBluetoothDevice):

```
self.selectedDevice = IOBluetoothDevice(address: deviceAddress)
```

Error : Cannot convert value of type 'BluetoothDeviceAddress' to expected argument type 'UnsafePointer!'

Best,

Antoine

Comment: Why do you have to *allocate* the memory? Why not just `let/var deviceAddress = BluetoothDeviceAddress()` ?

Comment: @MartinR not working, see my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your direct question: Acquiring a typed pointer from a raw
pointer is called "binding" in Swift and done with `bindMemory()`:

```
let ptr = malloc(MemoryLayout<BluetoothDeviceAddress>.size)! // Assuming that the allocation does not fail
let deviceAddressPtr = ptr.bindMemory(to: BluetoothDeviceAddress.self, capacity: 1)
deviceAddressPtr.initialize(to: BluetoothDeviceAddress())
// Use deviceAddressPtr.pointee to access pointed-to memory ...

let selectedDevice = IOBluetoothDevice(address: deviceAddressPtr)
// ...

deviceAddressPtr.deinitialize(count: 1)
free(ptr)
```

Instead of malloc/free, one would use the allocate/release methods
of `Unsafe(Mutable)Pointer` in Swift:

```
let deviceAddressPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<BluetoothDeviceAddress>.allocate(capacity: 1)
deviceAddressPtr.initialize(to: BluetoothDeviceAddress())
// Use deviceAddressPtr.pointee to access pointed-to memory ...

let selectedDevice = IOBluetoothDevice(address: deviceAddressPtr)
// ...

deviceAddressPtr.deinitialize(count: 1)
deviceAddressPtr.deallocate(capacity: 1)
```

See [SE-0107 UnsafeRawPointer API](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0107-unsaferawpointer.md)
for more information about raw pointers and binding.

*However,* it is usually easier to create a value of that type directly
and pass that as inout expression with `&`. Example:

```
var deviceAddress = BluetoothDeviceAddress()
// ...

let selectedDevice = IOBluetoothDevice(address: &deviceAddress)
// ...
```

Comment: Amazing, it is working perfectly, thank you for learning me this !!